# Configure the PayPal approval page

Tags: rest, api, paypal

I want my users to pay me through PayPal, I am using the Rest API according to this:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

In the second step "Get payment approval" I redirect to "approval_url". I want all the transaction to "happen" at PayPal and then just receive the confirmation, that everything went well.

The problem is, that this "approval_url" (at paypal.com) does not show the amount of money of the transaction. It also asks for shipping address (which I don't need). It also says "You'll be able to review your order before you complete your purchase." - they expect me to do a next step at my site before executing the payment, but I want everything to happen at PayPal, so I execute the payment right after Paypal redirects back to my site.

Can I configure the approval page at PayPal, so it guides the payer through everything?